# Simulate a smooth timeseries in Python

Tags: python, time-series

I want to use Python to generate some data that will simulate a fairly smooth wandering timeseries - similar to the following plot.

[image]

I originally started with a random walk, but if I made my standard deviation small, the data did not wander enough, and if I made the standard deviation too large, the plot is not smooth at all.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just apply a rolling moving average to your results:

```
from numpy import sqrt

annualized_vol = .30  # 30%
lag = 30
random_normals = np.random.randn(1000)  # 1,000 trading days.
daily_vol = sqrt(annualized_vol) * sqrt(1 / 252.)  # 252 trading days in a year.
random_daily_log_returns = random_normals * daily_vol
df = pd.DataFrame(random_daily_log_returns).cumsum()
df.rolling(lag).mean().plot()
```

The bigger the lag and the smaller the vol, the smoother the series

Comment: Any reference for this approach? I am curious to learn what does the constant "252." do here? And what's the distribution of the data points, e.g., a normally distributed around 0.0 with a certain standard deviation?

Comment: Vol is the annualized volatility (.30 = 30%), so vol * sqrt(1/252) is the standard deviation of daily returns (there are 252 trading days in a calendar year). For a single day, expected return is assumed to be zero. Daily returns are assumed to be normally distributed.  Although the sample is just meant to simulate stock returns for sample data to demonstrate how rolling works for the purpose of smoothing.